# Is there any CDN source or any other source from where I can refer the CSSPIE3 js?

Tags: html, css, cdn, host, google-cdn

I had previously posted a question in [stack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17594850/thin-spacer-css-not-working-properly-in-ie-8-and-ie-7) and got an answer from Spudley there to use the [CSSPIE3 Library](http://css3pie.com/documentation/pie-js/) `(PIE.js version 1.0)` . I have used it and it works perfectly for me .

However, i have to download it in my local and refer it from there.

Is there any CDN or host which hosts this js like `jquery.js` ?

If there is such a host, then i can directly refer it using `http(s)` instead of downloading and using it from my local .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like jsDelivr has it hosted: [jsdelivr.com](http://www.jsdelivr.com/#!css3pie)